# Can one modifiy an argument within its macro?

Tags: macros

I wish to give a default value to a series of arguments when they are empty.
I could make a test prior the use of the argument and modify the value just before each of the usage. I could even make a macro to do so. I could build a macro that encapsulate the initial macro that would "process" the arguments.
A more elegant way would be to modify the argument, right at the beginning of the macro. Is it possible ?

I wish I could change the value in `#1`, something like `\def#1{...}`:

```
\def\DisplayNumber#1{
\def#1{\ifx&#1& 0\else#1\fi} % if argument empty, make #1 equal to 0
Result is : #1}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the community with your use-case via a minimal example? Something tangible that highlights what you mean by "modify [a] macro argument"?

Comment: @egreg : Thanks for editing, I tried to do that with {} (code sample) but had not the result awaited (instead, I lost the carriage returns).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is adding the conditional at the point of use:

```
\def\DisplayNumber#1{%
  Result is: \ifx&#1&0\else#1\fi
}
```

Instead of the `\ifx&#1&` test for emptyness, you can use

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
```

provided you have e-TeX extensions enabled.

You can also define a utility macro:

```
\def\printifempty#1#2{\ifx&#2&#1\else#2\fi}
```

and your macro can be

```
\def\DisplayNumber#1{%
  Result is: \printifempty{0}{#1}%
}
```

---

A “generic” strategy for changing arguments is to define an “external” and an “internal” macro. With the help of `expl3` one can avoid cumbersome code with scores of `\expandafter` and `\romannumeral`.

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \test_internal_macro:nnnnnn
 {
  \internalmacro{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \test_internal_macro:nnnnnn { ffffff }

\cs_new:Nn \test_external_macro:nnnnnn
 {
  \test_internal_macro:ffffff
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 } { 0 } { #1 } }
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 } { 0 } { #2 } }
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 } { 0 } { #3 } }
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #4 } { 0 } { #4 } }
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #5 } { 0 } { #5 } }
   { \tl_if_blank:nTF { #6 } { 0 } { #6 } }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \externalmacro \test_external_macro:nnnnnn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\internalmacro#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \bigskip Calling {\tt\string\externalmacro}\par
  This is arg \#1: #1\par
  This is arg \#2: #2\par
  This is arg \#3: #3\par
  This is arg \#4: #4\par
  This is arg \#5: #5\par
  This is arg \#6: #6\par
}

\externalmacro{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}

\externalmacro{A}{}{}{D}{E}{F}

\externalmacro{}{}{}{}{}{}

\bye
```

The `\externalmacro` command is defined to call `\internalmacro` with “normalized” arguments: if one of them is blank, `0` is substituted.

This calls `\test_internal_macro:ffffff`, which is a wrapper around `\internalmacro` that's the one you give the “real” definition.

[image]

Comment: Sure, as I mentioned in the question, these are ways to do it. But, that's the problem with the very minimal, I have several usage of the argument. I wish something more "elegant", more readable also at the point of usage of the argument.

Comment: @user1771398, store the value in a macro, and do the test at the storing stage.

Comment: @daleif interesting idea : it means in fact a transfer to another set of "variables", let say \a,\b... It is very near from the encapsulation alternative, but with other names than #1,#2 etc.

Comment: @user1771398 another benefit is that you can use these in the end part of a normal `\newenvironment` definition. There env args does not apply (can be done using `xparse`). Also see the `etoolbox` package for various useful macroing tools.

Comment: @user1771398 What's the problem with `\printifempty`? I'd avoid doing `\def` inside the replacement text of `\DisplayNumber` if expandable alternatives are available.

Comment: @egreg \printifempty is a working solution. The drawbacks I see are linked to the context : I have quite a lot of arguments (at least 6) and I use them several times within the macro ; the macro is less readable with \printifempty around each argument used. My #1 solution would be to encapsulate the original macro with a macro with the same arguments and whose job is just to replace empty arguments with 0. I also think to manage this default value problem using the xkeyvalue mechanism (either preset or default value).

Comment: Shall I understand from all your contributions that there is no mechanism to change the value of an argument within a macro ? An argument is immutable then ?

Comment: @user1771398 Your questions are far from clear; for example, it's not explicit what flavor of TeX you're using, so I assumed Plain. Look whether the new code does what you wish.

Comment: @user1771398 The argument place holder is replaced by TeX at the point of macro expansion. From the macro level POV we never see `#1` we see the replacement text.

Comment: @ egreg sorry if my questions are unclear. In fact the central question is : "can I change the value of an argument inside a macro, just as you can do it in many (not all) languages ?". The rest is just an illustration, a context to justify why it could be interesting to be able to change the value of an argument. That is the reason why I gave alternatives I implicitly found less attractive than changing the value of an argument. And Joseph just brought the answer : a definite NO !

Comment: Considering the negative answer, my second best solution is the use of two macros, one embed in another ; the external one whose sole goal is to "rectify" arguments before passing them to the internal and original macro. That is the strategy you egreg implemented beginning with "A generic strategy ...".